# Deadlock when using runBlocking coroutine for retrieve Firebase's AuthUI.signOut() result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlinx.coroutines

I currently learning how to use Kotlin coroutines for Android applications. And one of the things that fascinates me a lot is a possibility to treat asynchronous procedures synchronously.

So, my toy application based on MVVM architecture pattern and using Firebase to implement sign in/out functionality. And there is a SignOut use case:

```
class FirebaseSignOut @Inject constructor(private val firebaseAuthUi: AuthUI) : SignOut {
    private lateinit var signOutResult: SignOutResult

    override fun execute(context: Context): SignOutResult {
        runBlocking {
            signOutResult = getSignOutResult(context)
        }

        return signOutResult
    }

    private suspend fun getSignOutResult(context: Context): SignOutResult {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            firebaseAuthUi.signOut(context)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        continuation.resume(SignOutSuccess)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        continuation.resume(SignOutError)
                    }
                    .addOnCanceledListener {
                        continuation.resume(SignOutCancel)
                    }
        }
    }

}
```

### The problem

is that blocking started with runBlocking is never unlocks.

I have figured out that coroutines logic itself is not a problem by replacing getSignOutResult() by mock, for example:

```
private suspend fun getSignOutResult(context: Context): SignOutResult {
    delay(500)
    return SignOutError
}
```

Then I was able to track the blocking til this part of Firebase's AuthUI:

```
return Tasks.whenAll(
        signOutIdps(context),
        maybeDisableAutoSignIn
).continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java#L325

```
private Task<Void> signOutIdps(@NonNull Context context) {
    ...
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).signOut();
}
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java#L403

and figure out that maybeDisableAutoSignIn Task is never starts. So, deadlock happening somewhere inside GoogleSignIn's signOut(), which is unable to trace.

### Question

Does anybody have an idea why such a deadlock can possibly happen? And any suggestion how to solve the problem is greatly welcome.

### Configuration details

I use currently latest versions of Kotlin and Firebase libraries

```
firebaseCoreVersion = '16.0.4'
firebaseUiVersion = '4.1.0'
kotlinVersion = '1.3.0'
kotlinCoroutinesVersion = '1.0.0'
```

AuthUI settled to use only Google sign in.

---

**! PLEASE NOTE** that I know I can make signOutResult variable observable. But in this case execute will not be able to **return** a result. And I really want to do it because such implementation is easy mockable for tests. And the fact that runBlocking blocks main thread for a sign out is acceptable in my case - it makes sense that UI is unavailable during the procedure, since user interface changes significantly depending on authentication state.

Comment: Is `execute` method invoked from another firebase callback?

Comment: *And the fact that runBlocking blocks main thread for a sign out procedure is acceptable in my case.* it's bad practice nonetheless. Don't do it

Comment: @qwwdfsad `execute` called on logout button click, not directly though but via ViewModel, which holds all necessary for current view use cases. So, no, not from another firebase callback

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but in my case Firestore's put callbacks are not called when using runBlocking. I replaced runBlocking with `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`, as suggested here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md, and this fixed the issue. I am still investigating if the `GlobalScope` part or the `Dispatchers.Main` part is important. The latter means that the coroutine will run on the UI thread, which may be relevant for Firebase.